# Are Unity game objects managed or unmanaged resources?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, idisposable

I have a class which instantiates a few unity game objects in a scene hierarchy. This class implements IDisposable. Should I handle these game objects as they were managed or unmanaged resources?

I am following the [Dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-5), so where should I put calls like GameObject.Destroy(myGameObject)?

Thank you

**Edit**:
Ok, lets say I want to destroy the game objects instantiated by this class when it goes out of scope. How would you proceed then?

**Edit 2:**
I was testing the dispose. And I have found a **solution**. It doesnt work automatically, because GameObject.Destroy(myGameObject) cant be called from different thread. It will throw an error CompareBaseObjectsInternal. So, when no longer needed I call myClass.Dispose(). Also it seems irrelevant whether I handle Unity GameObject as managed or unmanaged.

```
myMain()
{
    DisposeTestClass test = new DisposeTestClass();
    //...
    test.Dispose();
}


class DisposeTestClass : System.IDisposable
{

    public GameObject uselessGameobject { get; private set; }

    public DisposeTestClass()
    {           
        uselessGameobject = new GameObject("Useless gameobject");
    }

    #region IDisposable
    private bool _disposed;

    ~DisposeTestClass()
    {
        Debug.Log("~DisposeTestClass()");

        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Debug.Log("Dispose()");

        this.Dispose(true);
        System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Debug.Log("Dispose(bool)");

        if(_disposed)
        {
            Debug.Log("Disposed. Return.");
            return;
        }           

        if(disposing)
        {
            Debug.Log("Disposing of managed resources...");

            // clean up managed resources
            /*
            if(uselessGameobject != null)
            {
                GameObject.Destroy(uselessGameobject);
                Debug.Log("Game object destroyed.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Game object is null.");
            }*/

        }

        Debug.Log("Cleaning up unmanaged resources...");
        // clean up unmanaged resources

        if(uselessGameobject != null)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(uselessGameobject);
            Debug.Log("Game object destroyed.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Game object is null.");
        }

        // set the flag
        Debug.Log("Setting the disposed flag.");
        this._disposed = true;
    }
    #endregion

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't implement IDisposable. But you can :).

"so where should I put call GameObject.Destroy(myGameObject)" And when you want your objects to be destroyed? Actually that doesn't matter whether you call myContainer.Dispose() or GameObject.Destroy(gObj).

The only reason to implement IDisposable for you is to write "convient" code like:

```
using(var container = new MyContainer())
using(var somethingElse = new MyObject())
{
    \\Logic for container and somethingElse 
}
```

But in Unity this makes no sense. I can hardly imagine case when in an Update GameObjects are created and then destroyed.

Comment: Well it is actually the class is not a container. It just references the game objects in a scene. They continue to exist even after the instance of the class cease to be. See my edit.

Comment: I just used "container" because of lack of context. For destroying in Unity use GameObject.Destroy. Even after that, memory might be still occupied by gameobject unless GC collects it. Either IDisposable will not help you in deleting object entirely. It's purpose is to release unmanaged resources. GameObject is not an unmanaged resource and thus no IDisposable is required for it. 
Continue to exist means visible on scene?

Comment: Yes, those gameobjects stay in the scene in hierarchy.

Comment: Are they greyed or look like normal ones. Can you find them on scene if exceution is paused?

Comment: Yes, they stayed there. Not grey. 
Timur, I managed to solve this. I will post code soon.

Answer (score 2):

Huh, I think you slightly misunderstood what `IDisposable` and `using` statement is used for. You shouldn't implement `IDisposable` everywhere just to get rid of an object - this is garbage collector role, it knows better when an object shoyld be disposed.

`IDisposable` and `using` statement are used as a `try/finally` statement(of course it is much more complicated under the hood) and ensure that an object is removed/resolved right after it is not used anymore. It is not always a managed/unmanaged resource issue.

Using `using` statement won't ensure that your game object will be disposed. It all depends on the fact whether there are another objects pointing to it. Since it looks like a root object, I believe it will be held as long as possible by GC. Note that even if GC call `Dispose()` on your object, as long as it is referenced, it will be stay on the special queue until it is released.

On the other hand if your `GameObject` is less the `Game`, more the `Object`, you shouldn't consider disposing it using `IDisposable` as long as it is not somehow connected with some connection/file/external resource. GC will claim memory as soon as your object is considered garbage. Just take into consideration, that `IDisposable` is something which CLR treats a bit different and is not always the way to go.

**EDIT**

According to your question from edit - basically when a objects goes out of scope, you do nothing - if GC considers it garbage, it will be removed with the closest GC collection that occur. That's why C# is considered managed language and why you do not release memory on your own.

Comment: I understand what do you say about garbage collector, see my edit.

Comment: Well, the gameobjects created by the class still exist in the scene even after the instance of the class goes out of scope. I can write method named something like Cleanup or MyDispose which Destroys gameobjects and call it manually after I do not intend to work with the instance of the class. But it would be convenient for Destroys to be handled in Dispose.

Comment: If your objects still exists in your scene it means that they are somehow rooted. Could you elaborate on " created by the class still exist in the scene even after the instance of the class goes out of scope"?

Comment: GC doesn't call Dispose method. And CLR treats IDisposable like any other interface.  Finalizer, that is often part of correct implementation IDisposable, that shows that object should be treated specially by GC.

Comment: @TimurMannapov +1 True, it is kind of mental shortcut - CLR calls Finalizer, which can call Dispose although it is not guaranteed. It is just a convention and GC will call Dispose indirectly, if it is called explicitely in Finalizer.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I want to achieve. Its not about freeing the memory. I just took the approach of IDisposable to automate the process. Its about destroying the gameobjects in the scene created by this class. And I wanted it to happened automatically when instance of class goes out of scope. I posted the code.